# autohotkey focus no title

Tags: focus, autohotkey

I have been trying to get focus for an windows, in a software installation process. The window is without a title. The script keeps failing. Can someone let me know if there is something I can change on my script?

This should work to click the ok button:

```
 Sleep, 4000.
 Send, {control down}
 MouseClick, Left, 300, 185,
 Send, {Control up}
```

The results are that it opens Google Chrome next to the Windows start menu, instead of clicking on the determined spot on the open window in the middle of the desktop.

My full script is below:

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
;#Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

Sleep, 1000 ;language selection and next.
Send, {tab}
Sleep, 500
Send, {tab}
Sleep, 500
Send, {tab}
Sleep, 500
Sleep, 2000
Send, {Enter}

Sleep, 1000 ;directory and installation.
Send, {tab}
Sleep, 500
Send, {tab}
Sleep, 500
Send, {tab}
Sleep, 500
Send, {tab}
Sleep, 500
Send, {tab}
Sleep, 5000
Send, {Enter}
Sleep, 500
Send, {tab}
Sleep, 5000 ;for installation wait time.
Send, {Enter}   ;finish.

Sleep, 7000
Run "myexecutable.exe"

Sleep, 4000 ;focus attempt 2.
Send, {control down}
MouseClick, Left, 300, 185,
Send, {Control up} ;for association OK.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use mouse clicks in relative mode:

```
CoordMode, Mouse, Window
```

This will make the coordinates of the click relative to the *active window* instead of the screen.

So calculate the new coordinates for the position on the window you need to click on, and make sure that window is active.

To get the window handle, use the executable name of the program. For example to activate a window, instead of the parameter `WinTitle` use `ahk_exe` and the process name:

```
WinActivate, ahk_exe myexecutable.exe
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The actual problem is that the window does not 'take' focus. It does not show a title, and it does not have a 'hidden' title.

I did try different ways to take focus for that pop-up but none worked. Interestingly, trying relative coordinates to the SCREEN sometimes worked, yet failed (with exact same coding) 97% of the time.

Also, it worked with a little more success (50%) when I tested it as an isolated snippet, plotting for the coordinates (blank window title option) for the exact coding.